# Apache restart says [OK] but no process is there

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm running Ubuntu Intrepid with Apache2.  I was installing php5-cli, and after it was installed apache wouldnt restart.  i get no errors it just tells me [OK].  htop, top, and ps -aux arent returning any apache processes.  any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see anything recorded in the relevant log files?

Usually in /var/log/apache2

Comment: nothing in any of the log files. that would indicate an error.

Comment: found the actual log file.  whoever set this server up before put the error.log in a different location....  eaccelerator was pulling errors saying it needed to be rebuilt.  rebuilt it and restarted apache. everythings fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for 'apache' or are you looking for 'httpd'? httpd is the actual Apache server process.

Something like: ps ax | grep http should show you if there is any running Apache processes.

Comment: when i run ps aux | grep http:
centro    5816  0.0  0.2   6236   648 pts/0    R+   18:29   0:00 grep http

nothing more than the grep.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a service httpd stop, then a start and grep for the service. Does anything show up then?

Also try a tail -f on /var/log/messagse and see what the system says when you perform any of the start/stop/restart commands.

Answer (score 0):

the problem that i found when something like this happens is apache unable to write a log file and it usually hiccups there, so make sure all of your logs path are correct